# How do you map a pointer location to /proc/self/{map,mem}?

Tags: memory, proc, virtual-memory

I am trying to write a light weight test to determine if sensitive parameters are getting zero'd in active memory after use. Here is what I thought would work:

1. Get the pointer location of the sensitive parameters (byte array) form the application
2. Determine if it is in the `[heap]` or `[stack]` by looking at the ranges in `/proc/self/map` (this is also meant to note where the runtime put the variable)
3. Open up `/proc/self/mem` and read the array's values

The issue is I am clearly missing an mapping from the pointer location the application  reports and the address ranges given by `/proc/self/map`. Basically the pointer printed by the application does not fall within the range of the heap or stack.

```
2022/10/19 09:59:39 the point to byte array 0xc0000a6060
2022/10/19 09:59:39 [heap] start 7c0000 stop 7e1000
2022/10/19 09:59:39 [stack] start 7ffcfa467000 stop 7ffcfa489000
```

How do I get the mapping of the pointer value to the ranges in `/proc/self/map`?

Comment: `[heap]` and `[stack]` are just linux "default interpretations" of where the heap and the stack are. A process can map memory at arbitrary locations. You can have as many stacks as you want, if you know how to handle them, and it's pretty common to not only have one continuous heap for memory allocations, but multiple arenas – especially in languages that support multiple threads.

Comment: so, does your pointer fall into any of the other mappings? If not, accessing it would be a SEGFAULT.

Comment: @Marcus I think the issue might be that the pointer is giving the location of virtual memory and `/proc/self/map` is giving the physical memory location. Is there any way to get the paging table mapping?

Comment: no, it cannot give you physical addresses; these do not exist towards userspace. The mapping addresses are all virtual addresses.

Comment: It seems like it _might_ be possible with [/proc/self/pagemap](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt). I'll give it a try a report back

Comment: as said, you'll really have to look into all the non-file-backed mappings, anyways :) This might be a lot of memory! And saving that might fault in a lot of memory you didn't actually use this far.